# JBehave steps makred as PENDING randomly

Tags: java, jbehave

Heyy!

I have a bunch of story files with some scenarios, calling a WSDL service and checking the answer. The step functions have been written properly (as in no exceptions are thrown and it asserts true when it has to and vv.) and the service returns a valid answer.

My problem is in the case of some scenarios, I get steps (which has been defined as And in the story file, after a Given, or a Then) are getting marked as Pending, still IntelliJ puts the same green tick besides it as any other successful step.

The next time I run the test then they usually aren't pending anymore, but these marks coming and going randomly, which is kinda annoying, because I can't be sure if the step has actually been called or if it had any effect.

I can't show a code unfortunately, but one guess of mine is in the case of Given steps I just collect a number of Condition<>-s (from AssertJ) and don't actually do an assertion in the given step, but assert them all in the one and only When step.

Comment: Do these "And" steps have otherwise matching Given, When, and/or Then steps?  In other words, could the step finder get confused with a "The headers are sent" that has both a When and a Then but the story file might have an "And" following a Given (just an  example to set your line of thinking...)  Perhaps show a section of your story file and your steps file? (Had to remove at signs (@) - editor thought I was trying to tag multple people)

Comment: FWIW the pending is almost always (if not always) the runner unable to find the matching step, for whatever reason.  I get that you're saying it works sometimes and not others, but I've never found any other reason for PENDING to show up other when there was a typo in a step definition or story step line.

Comment: every step is unique in a way that a Given step is always used as Given step, etc.
The interesting part is even tho the step is marked as pending in the IntelliJ tests part (before the step name there is a [PENDING]), however if I rerun the test without any modification, or without the service answering differently, the step will not be [PENDING] again

Comment: Also, if I delete the Given annotation from the function, the step is Pending again, but this time with the obvious error message that the step was not found.
If i leave the annotation, the step will become accepted, but still be PENDING every once in a while